# Is .txt extension necessary in File() constructor?

Tags: java, android, file, fileoutputstream

Like in the method i have attached i have used practiceData.txt i am getting same results while using just practiceData in file constructor so is it ok to use file without any extension or txt is better?

```
private void saveData(String data) {
    File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "practiceData.txt");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
        saveStatus = "Data was successfully saved.";
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        saveStatus = "Error occurred: " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter what file extension you use, it just tells the OS how to open the file. So yes, you can use no extension and it will work just as well.

If you intend the file to be opened manually via another application, it may be helpful to use a standard extension however.